# Do I need and how do I calibrate movesense sensor?

Tags: calibration, movesense

I am trying to implement ARHS algorithm and for this I need to know if my magnetometer is properly calibrated. Can I ask you how can I calibrate movesense sensor? Or it is calibrated out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic magnetometer "soft-iron"-calibration out of box, but it does not take into account the magnetization of the individual sensor or battery or "hard-iron" calibration. So those have to be added if accurate magnetic field measurements are wanted.

For AHRS-algorithms, another important part is estimation of gyro bias. Some of the AHRS-algorithms do this automatically, others need it done before operation. Gyro-bias changes quite slowly over time so it does not need to be done often, maybe once a day depending on the required accuracy.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*